# How to clip Raster using multiple polygons and Python?

Tags: python, raster, arcgis-10.1, clip

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [clipping a raster by multiple datasets or polygons](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37325/clipping-a-raster-by-multiple-datasets-or-polygons)

I have polygon layer and DEM and I want to write a program using python to cut the raster into multi-raster based on the polygon features.so please anybody can help??

---

actually I am using ArcGIS 10.1 full license

---

actually (clipping a raster by multiple datasets or polygons.) does not work for my case. I have wrote this code:............. 
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *

## path name variables

polygonLayer = r'....'
output = r'......'
raster = r'.....'

## name of ID field

fieldName = "OBJECKTID"
cursor = arcpy.SearchCursor(polygonLayer)
for poly in cursor:
    mask = poly.OBJECTID

## create feature layer of current mask polygon

```
whereClause = '"' + focusField + '"=' + " ' " + mask + "'"
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(polygonLayer, 'currentMask', whereClause)
```

but I got an error with whereClause......... so please any help how can I create feature layer fro each row...... so then I can use them to clip the raster..... thanks in advance

Comment: If you are using ArcGIS, then see [clipping a raster by multiple datasets or polygons](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37325/clipping-a-raster-by-multiple-datasets-or-polygons).